# Concept of matched filter maximising SNR

Tags: communication, digital-communications, receiver, snr

[image]
[image]
The above question is a solved question from Digital Communication by Proakis . The question is about matched filter where I know matched filter is used to maximise the signal to noise ratio at the receiver to 2E/No where E is the energy of the signal which is input to the matched filter , the output is sampled at T, where T is the duration of the input signal. However in the second example SNR by sampling at T would become 0 since the output itself is 0, so in this case how is matched filter maximising the SNR ?

Comment: Where is the second example?

Comment: The 2nd signal is orthognal signal and is not just sampled at T. Each are integrated over an interval. This part of a "matched filter"  needs synchronous integration over the correct interval.

Comment: @ThePhoton  The second example meaning the second signal considered in the question .

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Thank you for the reply. But second is orthogonal to its impulse response? But then the first signal and its impulse response are also orthogonal . What is synchronous integration and what is correct interval?

Comment: An Ideal Receiver is coherently **matched** in both signal spectrum and time. regardless of how many phase signals exist ; 1 or 2 thus the time integration intervals are matched separately but the jitter error in the clocks are additive to the noise of the SNR for the signal and often ignored in calculations